# String Conversion in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my program, I'm allowing the user to input some words into a textfield. Then my program will use these words to form a html string. The string will then be used in NSURL so I can connect to the website.

This method works great for english words. But when I input some chinese (or korean) in there, I does not work. Thus I believe that I need to convert the inputed data before passing it to NSURL. However I could not find a way to do this.
Here's an example of how my code looks like.

```
NSString *searchedString = theSearchBar.text;

NSString *urlToBeSearched = [[NSString alloc] 
     initWithFormat:@"http://www.awebsite.com/search/%@", 
     searchedString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] 
    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToBeSearched]
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:50];
NSURLConnection *tempCon =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
             delegate:self];
```

Then of course releasing them later.

For example, when searchedString = 你好, the urlLink will be  [http://www.awebsite.com/search/你好](http://www.awebsite.com/search/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD). NSURLConnection doesn't like that and will give me "Bad Url" error.
However, if the urlLink is "%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD" it will give me the correct link.

Comment: Could you please post your *real* code.  This will not compile and you never use searchedString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of characters allowed in a URI is pretty much limited to a subset of US-ASCII (see [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)).  That means your Chinese characters must be percent escaped in the URI.  The documentation for [NSURL +URLWithString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB) says the string must conform to the RFC so you need to percent escape the string *before* calling that method.

Fortunately, NSString has a method that will allow you to do that called [-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB).  You still need to choose a suitable encoding and which one you choose depends on how the server decodes the URL string. The easiest option is probably to use UTF-8 at both ends. You need to do something like:

```
NSString* searchedString = [theSearchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* urlToBeSearched = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.awebsite.com/search/%@", searchedString];

// everything else the same, except you don't need to release urlToBeSearched
```

Comment: One more question. How do I decode searchedString back into Chinese again?

Comment: You'll need to reverse the actions.  On your server, you should chop the front off so you only have the bit after "search/" then you need to reverse the URL encoding.  How you do this depends on the language your server side is written in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try encoding your search-string?

`[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:/encoding-of-choice/];`

Not sure what encoding you would use for chinese characters though.