# How do I create an NSURL using non-English characters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried constructing the following NSURL for a custom URL scheme:

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tweetie:///post?message=안녕 모두"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but it doesn't perform correctly.  How would you construct such a URL with non-English elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you may only send US-ASCII characters in URI strings. Try adding percent escapes to your string before sending it:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:
   [@"tweetie:///post?message=안녕 모두" 
        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

See [String Conversion in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649966/string-conversion-in-objective-c)